# WordPress add_user_meta / update_user_meta not working (resolved)

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add the _capabilities and _level meta data to existing users in a multisite setup so they also have access to the new section, our forum.

The forum is the 3rd site on the network and I want to grant everyone the basic access rights as Contributor. Some users I already added manually to the usermeta table so I check in the script if the user meta_key already exists or not. And to ensure the script doesn't mess with the admin accounts I only want to run the script for user IDs above 3.

When I try below code, I use it in a temp plugin which I will only run once, then I just get a whole bunch of WordPress error messages thrown at me which I somehow can't really decipher to get it working :(

The issue is somehow with the add_ / update_user_meta functions... What am I overlooking?

```
$prefix = 'tbl_prefix_3_';
$cap = [ "contributor" => true ]; 
$lvl = 1;

$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
asort( $users );
       
foreach( $users as $user ) {
  $user_id = intval( $user->ID );
  
  if( $user_id > 3 ) {
     
    $check = get_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix . 'capabilities', true );
    if( empty( $check ) ) {
        add_user_meta(    $user_id, $prefix . 'capabilities', $cap );
    } else {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix . 'capabilities', $cap );
    }
    
    $check = get_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix . 'user_level', true );
    if( empty( $check ) ) { 
        add_user_meta(    $user_id, $prefix . 'user_level', $lvl );
    } else {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $prefix . 'user_level', $lvl );
    } 
 
  }    
}
```

The errors:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_user_by()
> in /home/.../wp-includes/meta.php:1652 Stack trace:
> #0 /home/.../wp-includes/meta.php(176): get_object_subtype('user', 4)
> #1 /home/.../wp-includes/user.php(1043): update_metadata('user', 4, 'tbl_prefix_capab...', Array, '')
> #2 /home/.../wp-content/plugins/assign_rights_to_users.php(33): update_user_meta(4, 'tbl_prefix_capab...', Array)
> #3 /home/.../wp-settings.php(391): include_once('/home/...') #4 /home/.../wp-config.php(253): require_once('/home/...')
> #5 /home/.../wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/...')
> #6 /home/.../wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/...') #7 /ho in **/home/.../wp-includes/meta.php** on line **1652**
>
> **Notice:** is_embed was called **incorrectly**. Conditional query tags do not
> work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false.
> Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.  (This message
> was added in version 3.1.0.) in **/home/.../wp-includes/functions.php** on
> line **5313**
>
> **Notice:** is_search was called **incorrectly**. Conditional query tags do
> not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return
> false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This
> message was added in version 3.1.0.) in
> **/home/.../wp-includes/functions.php** on line **5313**
>
> There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your
> site admin email inbox for instructions.

Comment: The error is coming from here `/wp-content/plugins/assign_rights_to_users.php(33):`

Comment: Yeah - correct, that is the temp plugin I created with the above code. But why do I get the errors for the add_/update_user_meta functions? I have all the parameters supplied which are necessary...

Comment: Where did you use `get_user_by()` function?

Comment: I'm not calling that one directly. I guess it's coming from the $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) ); line. When I output that then I get a correct array with all the user IDs in the database which I then want to loop through in the next section.

Comment: I can also retreive the list of user IDs via:   `$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => 'ID' ) );  foreach( $users as $user ) {  $user_id = intval( $user );`

But still the same error messages pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had forgotten to include it in a hook so the WordPress stuff was not properly available in the plugin :|

I now placed it into an admin_init hook so I activate the plugin, let it do it's magic, and than deactivate and remove the plugin again. I also simplified the whole thing, so only using the update_user_meta now.

Anyway, this is the working result:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: 000 FIX MISSING USER RIGHTS
 * Description: Activate, deactivate, check the results, remove the plugin!
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: golabs
 * @source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877257/3592696
 */

function fix_missing_user_rights() {
      
  $prefix = 'wp_prefix_';

  /**
   * Use one of the 2 methods:
   *   - manual array with user ids 
   *     OR
   *   - collect them from the database
   * Just comment out the method you don't want to use.
   */
  # $users = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ];
  $users = get_users( array( 'fields' => 'ID' ) ); asort( $users );
     
  foreach( $users as $user ){

      update_user_meta( $user, $prefix.'capabilities',   [ 'subscriber' => true ] );
      update_user_meta( $user, $prefix.'user_level',        0 );
      
      update_user_meta( $user, $prefix.'2_capabilities', [ 'customer' => true ] );
      update_user_meta( $user, $prefix.'2_user_level',      8 );
      
      update_user_meta( $user, $prefix.'3_capabilities', [ 'contributor' => true ] );
      update_user_meta( $user, $prefix.'3_user_level',      1 );

  } 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'fix_missing_user_rights' );
```